# Want to create Gmail like Swipeable Card using React JS (Not React Native)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to make Gmail like swipe cards in React Js,

I have already created the UI and all and have implemented Swiping using UseGeature and currently, I am using UseEffect to hide or show left or right buttons, It created a 20px movement then jumps to the required width as I am using UseEffect to show/hide buttons,
but the animation is not smooth,

So I tried using two layers, Buttons on the bottom Layer and the Main card on the top layer,
but now I am unable to click on buttons after swipe even after they are visible as the card lop layer is still present, the top later has a touch action of its on so cant propagate touch through it.

I can touch the buttons if I change Z-Index using useEffect but then it again makes the animation glitchy,

has anyone ever made something like this, I could refer to it or any other suggestions

Thanks in advance
[image]
(this is not the actual UI)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recognize swipe events in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70612769/how-do-i-recognize-swipe-events-in-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can this help you?

```js
$.fn.extend({
    createBtn: function () {
        var elmWidth = $("li", $(this)).width(),
            listType = $(this).listview("option", "inset") ? true : false,
            btnWidth = elmWidth < 300 && listType ? "35%" : elmWidth > 300 && !listType ? "25%" : "20%";
        $("li", $(this)).each(function () {
            var text = $(this).html();
            $(this).html($("<div/>", {
                class: "wrapper"
            }).append($("<div/>", {
                class: "go"
            }).text("Save").width(btnWidth)).append($("<div/>", {
                class: "item"
            }).text(text)).append($("<div/>", {
                class: "del"
            }).text("Delete").width(btnWidth)).css({
                left: "-" + btnWidth
            }).on("swipeleft swiperight vclick tap", function (e) {

                $(this).revealBtn(e, btnWidth);
            }) /**/ );
        });
    },
    revealBtn: function (e, x) {
        var check = this.check(x),
            swipe = e.type;
        if (check == "closed") {
            swipe == "swiperight" ? this.open(e, x, "left") : swipe == "swipeleft" ? this.open(e, x, "right") : setTimeout(function () {
                this.close(e);
            }, 0);
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
        if (check == "right" || check == "left") {
            swipe == "swiperight" ? this.open(e, "left") : swipe == "swipeleft" ? this.open(e, x, "right") : setTimeout(function () {
                this.close(e);
            }, 0);
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
        if (check !== "closed" && e.isImmediatePropagationStopped() && (swipe == "vclick" || swipe == "tap")) {
            this.close(e);
        }
    },
    close: function (e) {
        var check = this.check();
        this.css({
            transform: "translateX(0)"
        });
    },
    open: function (e, x, dir) {
        var posX = dir == "left" ? x : "-" + x;
        $(this).css({
            transform: "translateX(" + posX + ")"
        });
    },
    check: function (x) {
        var matrix = this.css("transform").split(" "),
            posY = parseInt(matrix[matrix.length - 2], 10),
            btnW = (this.width() * parseInt(x) / 100) / 1.1;
        return isNaN(posY) ? "closed" : posY >= btnW ? "left" : posY <= "-" + btnW ? "right" : "closed";
    }
});

$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $("ul").createBtn();
});
```

```css
div[data-roler="header"] h1 {
  background: #f90 !important;
}
li {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
li .wrapper {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 300ms ease;
    transition: transform 300ms ease;
}
.wrapper .go, .wrapper .item, .wrapper .del {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.9em;
    text-shadow: none;
    border-style: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper .item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper .go, .wrapper .del {
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ddd;
}
.wrapper .go {
    background: #009925;
    border-color: #009925;
}
.wrapper .del {
    background: #F90101;
    border-color: #F90101;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
         <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li>Swipe me 1</li>
            <li>Swipe me 2</li>
            <li>Swipe me 3</li>
            <li>Swipe me 4</li>
            <li>Swipe me 5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" data-tap-toggle="false">
         <h1>Hallo</h1>

    </div>
</div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: No, This one Shows a Button on Hover, I want the button to be visible only when the user swipes the card, and buttons are visible below it. The UI is made for touch screen mobile phones
Thnx btw

Comment: I updated it, better now? You can swipe left or right (save and delete)

Comment: Thanks ... I guess this would work. Thanks again

Comment: @VaibhavChopade can you mark this as solved?